# where exactly do we need exception handling for web-services on iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, exception, sudzc

I am a new iPhone developer and totally new to web-services as well. I had used http://www.sudzc.com/ to develop my obj-c code for my wsdl. I need to know that where exactly i need to handle exceptions in this code? Or the code generated by sudz itself takes care of the exception handling itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example code generated for your web service.  They give you the generic layout for the error handlers.  Should look something like this:

// Handle the response from webserviceConnection.

- (void) webserviceConnectionHandler: (BOOL) value {

  // Do something with the BOOL result

  NSLog(@"webserviceConnection returned the value: %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:value]);

}

Answer (score 0):

Generally the proxy classes from the WSDL has selector methods which gets called,when you do some operation/method call. So you just need to check it out what method (from service level) you are going to call and implement the selector method in your class.